# Ruby on Rails Save Using AJAX

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

In my Rails application, I'm looking for a way to save a post and come up with a notice saying "Saved." without redirecting anywhere.

Can I do this in the controller or do I have to use Ajax? If I have to use Ajax, is there an easy way to implement it?

Here are the create and update actions in my controller:

```
def create
  @document = current_user.documents.build(params[:document])

  if @document.save
    redirect_to @document.edit, notice: 'Saved'
  else
    render action: "new"
  end
end

def update
  @document = current_user.documents.find_by_url_id(params[:id])

  if @document.update_attributes(params[:document])
    redirect_to @document, notice: 'Saved'
  else
    render action: "edit"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're trying to replace the 'new document' form with an 'edit document' form as well as show an alert saying it's saved.

To be honest, probably the easiest way for you to do this is use jQuery to replace the whole form with a partial. It's not the slimmest and there are ways to do all the Javascript client-side but this would get you started.

Presuming you have your 'new document' form in a partial called `_new.html.erb` create a file called `create.js.erb` and put this in it:

```
$edit_form = "<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'new', :locals => {document: @document}) %>"
$("#document_form_container").html($edit_form)
```

Then make sure your form has `:remote => true` in the `form_for` tag.

Comment: Is that it? I have `_form.html.erb` and `new.html.erb`. I'm currently using jQuery so it'd be good to use that. Do I need to replace `#document_form_container` with my own ID?

Comment: Yes and replace `new` with `form` in your render :partial.

Comment: The new action in the controller? How would I do that? Apologies, I'm new to Rails

Comment: No, your partial is called _form.html.erb so you want to render that instead of new. `render :partial => 'form', :locals => {document: @document}`

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create a new controller action (and you probably shouldn't) then I suggest you set up your create and update actions to look like this:

```
def create
  @document = current_user.documents.build(params[:document])

  if @flag = @document.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  else
    render action: "new"
  end
end

def update
  @document = current_user.documents.find_by_url_id(params[:id])

  if @flag = @document.update_attributes(params[:document])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  else
    render action: "edit"
  end
end
```

Then in app/views/documents/create.js.erb:

```
var results_html;
var status;

<% if @flag %>
  results_html = $('<%= j(render("document"))%>');
  status = "success";
<% else %>
  results_html = $('');
  status = "failure";
<% end %>

$('destination').append(results_html); //assuming you're inserting a list item or some content besides the alert onto the page

alert(status); // replace this with your actual alert code
```

and in update.js.erb:

```
var results_html;
var status;

<% if @flag %>
  results_html = $('<%= j(render("document"))%>');
  status = "success";
<% else %>
  results_html = $('');
  status = "failure";
<% end %>

$('#<%= @document.id %>').replaceWith(results_html); //assuming you're replacing a list item or some content besides the alert onto the page.  also, make sure you're searching for the correct element id

alert(status); // replace this with your actual alert code
```

Hope this helps.  The key is that rails lets you define different templates for different access methods on a controller action.  When you make an AJAX request, you will get the js.erb view by default, which will allow you to manipulate the current page by returning javascript that will run when it is returned by the server.

Comment: What about adding remote true on the _form.html.erb?